# Como deve ser feito o registo das senhas numa base de dados?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Eu estou criando um programa em Java, conectado com uma base de dados, o meu problema estaa em se devo criar uma tebela nova pra guardar a senha e o nome de cada usuario ou se devo usar esses dados como atributos de cliente.

Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Impossível uma resposta certa. Só depende do seu caso. Se quiser aproveitar a base de dados de cadastro, pode, mas mesmo assim eu faria uma tabela separada (especialização daquele cadastro, numa tabela vinculada por id). Assim, se eu atualizo o cadastro de um "cliente usuário", o usuário é atualizado junto. Mas esse é o meu jeito de fazer, você tem que pensar no que é melhor ou mais conveniente para o seu caso específico. Pode ter mil respostas aqui, mas nenhuma vai ser "a correta".